# Package not found IntelliJ IDEA Skype4java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, skype, skype4java

I've been so frustrated, I can't even begin writing my plugin because I'm having such problems getting a simple testcase to compile.

I followed the guide on IDEAs website to add the library, which seemed to be successful because IntelliSense detects the packages/classes, but then I come to compile.. and package not found

Here's a screenshot: any advice is greatly appreciated thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, it appears to be picking up the lib in the IDE (detecting package/classes/methods etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you told IntelliJ that the library was the zip file containing all the distribution (sources, documentation, etc.). Extract the zip file, and make it point to the jar file that this zip probably contains.

Comment: Thanks alot, don't know how I could be so dumb! Fresh installed IDEA and assumed I'd not set something up right, all the time I was just being stuuupiddd! Tyvm finally I can get on!